# How can I style the current (today's date) in bold font?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need your help,

How can the CSS be modified such that it would allow the current (today's date) to be a in bold font?

I thought that this would be the correct style, but for some reason, it is not working:

```
.ui-datepicker-today {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about inner tag([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9bwG/)):

```
.ui-datepicker-today .ui-state-default {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

`ui-state-default` has `font-weight: normal` by default `jQuery UI` stylesheet. So better to override inner tag by class.

Answer (score 0):

```
.demo input{
font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Comment: You should never use `!important` if not necessary. Why should it be in this case?

Answer (score -1):

```
.ui-datepicker-today a{
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

There is a `font-weight: normal;` on the anchor inside the `td` you're targeting. You need to override that with `!important` or by using more specific identifiers